# .NET HTTP Handler -- How to Send Custom Response?

Tags: .net, http, handler

I have converted my custom (socket-based) server over to an HTTP Handler in IIS (.NET 4.0).

I have converted my client to send an HTTP GET in the proper format.

I do not want to change my client's response-handling code to parse out the HTML code.  That is a pain in the rear that is also unnecessary.  I do not need this server to work with a browser or be compatible with anything except my client.

So, I basically need the HTTP Handler (server) to send the response that the client expects -- without the "HTML/1.0", headers and whatnot.

I am using the HttpContext.Response.Write() method at the moment.  I figure there is either a way to write raw data to the response, or a way to delete all the headers and HTML tags around the data I want to send.

Thanks in advance for any help.
Dave

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are looking at this in a browser to verify, then what you may be seeing is the browsers attempt to *fix* your HTML for you.

For instance if I have this in my Handler:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    context.Response.Write("Hello World");
}
```

Then the Response Headers will look like this:

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>   Server: ASP.NET Development Server/10.0.0.0
>   Date: Sat, 03 Sep 2011 03:26:36 GMT
>   X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
>   Cache-Control: private
>   Content-Type: **text/html**; charset=utf-8
>   Content-Length: 11
>   Connection: Close

The actual content of the response is simply

> Hello World

You'll notice the default content type is **text/html**, however, you basically have full control over the response. You can clear the headers, add new ones, and set the content type accordingly:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    context.Response.ClearHeaders();
    context.Response.AddHeader("my-skillz", "being AWESOME!");
    context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
    context.Response.Write("Hello World");
}
```

Which will yield the following Response Headers:

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>   Server: ASP.NET Development Server/10.0.0.0
>   Date: Sat, 03 Sep 2011 03:40:14 GMT
>   X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
>   **my-skillz: being AWESOME!**
>   Cache-Control: private
>   Content-Type: **text/plain**; charset=utf-8
>   Content-Length: 11
>   Connection: Close

So there you have it. Take a look at the docs on [HttpResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhy78ycf.aspx) so you can see all that is available to you, and **you should be able to get exactly what you want out of the responses** without any extra headache, and no HTML anywhere in sight.

Comment: You're right about the "<html><body>...</body></html>".  The browser was adding that in.  The headers are still there though.  No worries I guess.  It's not a horrible modification to the client.  All I need to do is use String.split("\r\n\r\n") and use the second string.