# Can't set "Content-Type" in my generic handler

Tags: javascript, asp.net, mime-types, generic-handler

I have a very simple **Generic Handler**, which sends a simple alert to the client. I set the `Content-Type` header to be `application/x-javascript`, but what I get from server is a `text/html` content type.

Here is the code of my generic handler:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    context.Response.Clear();
    context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-javascript");
    context.Response.ContentType = "application/x-javascript";
    context.Response.Write("alert('javascript is here');");
    context.Response.Flush();
    context.Response.End();
}
```

Now, when I call this handler, via `http://domain/path/handler.ashx`, what I get in Firebug is:

[image]

Any idea what's wrong?

**PS:** I want to create a script delivery service, and the script is authored on the fly. That's why I use a dynamic generic handler to serve this script.

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing the response headers first:

```
context.Response.ClearHeaders()
...
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7291044